# HOW to impliment SQL 2012 send_dbmail with OAuth2

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-mail

Situation: we currently send emails from our sql 2012/asp app using the msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail process and implement multiple different domain accounts. It works (worked) well for us to send authorised emails from our application on behalf of our customers. Now that OAuth2 is being properly maintained, we now need to be able to connect to email accounts that are implementing OAuth2 for Authentication (or any of the other Authentication protocols eg encrypted password). Is this possible? Is the answer a different email agent? Who as solved this and how?

Answer (score 0):

> Is the answer a different email agent?

Yep. If you wanted to do it inside of SQL Server you could write some CLR code, but I wouldn't advise it.